# Android Studio Using private resources

Tags: android, android-studio

Acabo de instalar el Android Studio y me ocurre el siguiente problema cuando inicia y seleccionas un modelo básico pues te debería mostrar el Hello World! típico ya sabéis, pues no lo muestra y ademas me indica el siguiente error:

> The resource @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is marked as private in com.android.support:design  Private resources should not be referenced; the may not be present everywhere, and even where they are they may disappear without notice.  To fix this, copy the resource into your own project instead.

La verdad llevo dando vueltas por la red un rato y no encuentro la solución... si alguien puede guiarme es de agradecer.

Comment: https://ibb.co/nbgjoo asi me indica realmente

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado suprimiendo la "@" delante del string por si alguien mas le pasa . un saludo

Comment: Hmm, no creo que quitando la @ se solucione el problema, ya que así no estás referenciando al recurso...te dará algun problema por otro lado seguramente

Comment: Por cierto, lo olvidaba: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Tienes la siguiente cadena en tus String  <string name="app_scrolling_view_behavior">scroll view behavior</string> ?

Comment: Mi pregunta es, ¿en realidad necesitas esta cadena a la que haces referencia en tu "Hello World"? @R--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con respecto al error, definitivamente no es solución eliminar la "@" en:

```
@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior
```

ya que puede provocar problemas en tu aplicación, ya que no encontrara el recurso y pensará al compilar que es un atributo.

---

> ¿en realidad necesitas esta cadena a la que haces referencia en tu
>   aplicación "Hello World"?

Este recurso esta usado en una library, la mejor opción puedes copiarlo a tu proyecto, incluso esto es lo que sugiere el mensaje de error.

Revisando un poco, este recurso se encuentra dentro de la library de diseño, por lo tanto agrega a tu archivo `values.xml` de tu proyecto la entrada:

```
<string name="appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" translatable="false">android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior</string>
```

Para de esta forma tener el recurso en tu proyecto y evitar el error.

Revisa la documentación oficial acerca de [**Recursos Privados.**](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#PrivateResources)

---

Otra opción es deshabilitar el análisis para recursos marcados como privados, esto dentro de tu `build.gradle`, aunque no asegura el correcto funcionamiento de tu aplicación:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        disable 'PrivateResource'
    } 
}
```

Comment: Estupendo muchas Gracias por toda la info :D